# Deprecated Short(String) how to update?

Tags: java, deprecated, java-11, short

I'm handling this problem:

```
produto.setQuantidade(new Short("7"));
```

`Short` appears deprecated with a mark. How can I update this for above Java 9 versions? (Now, I have Java 11)

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason to parse a string here? Why not use `produto.setQuantidade((short)7);`?

Comment: Documentation exists

Comment: It's necessary to differentiate Integer, BigInt and Short when you use getters and setters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shall use `Short.valueOf`. This is taken from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Short.html#%3Cinit%3E(short))

> Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The
> static factory valueOf(short) is generally a better choice, as it is
> likely to yield significantly better space and time performance

*Note*: The public constructor is up `forRemoval` starting Java-16.

Comment: I wonder if `forRemoval` really means *for removal* or they're just trying to scare more people off from using them. JDK authors almost never break backwards compatibility without a really good reason. It's not like there's a maintenance burden on these classes either. I wonder if we're seeing a turning point where they finally get rid of some of the cruft that's built up over 25 years.

Comment: True, but, I don't see the `forRemoval` in the source code (yet? reference in here https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee1d592a9f53/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Short.java#l345). So, probably need to check with the editor where he got that information.

Comment: produto.setQuantidade(Short.valueOf("7"));
Thank you so much, it woks nicelly in JUnit.
Hibernate: select this_.codigo as codigo1_3_0_, this_.descricao as descrica2_3_0_ from Fabricante this_ where this_.codigo = ?
Hibernate: insert into Produto (descricao, fabricante, preco, quantidade) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: @kucing_terbang Not sure what precisely you linked to, but latest version of that file is here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Short.java#L352

Comment: @Michael these constructors have been marked “*deprecated*” with JDK 9 and “*deprecated, for removal*” in JDK 16. That’s quite some time and versions keeping backward compatibility and there will be some time and versions where the constructors still exist but marked as “*deprecated, for removal*”. There are good reasons to get rid of those constructors altogether. These wrapper classes are natural candidates for *value types* or for whatever future mechanism that treats these objects like primitive values, i.e. without a specific object identity. Which is incompatible with supporting `new`.

Comment: @Holger There is no requirement that they remove all these constructors before value types are introduced. They could decide that `new` will also be the keyword for instantiating a value type (in such a case "new" would then be a slight misnomer, but not the end of the word). In such case, calling `new Short(...)` would silently go from creating a new instance every time, to not doing that. Almost all code (except those that explicitly expect 2 instances for some reason) would continue to work.

Comment: @Holger I'm not saying they shouldn't remove these things. I wish they would. But the historical precedent suggests they will not, regardless of what some annotation says. Can you think of the last thing marked in the JDK as deprecated that has *actually* ended up being removed? I can't, because it almost never happens.

Comment: aa thanks @Michael, that's the link from openjdk mercurial repo. I got it from the website might missed some versioning I guess.

Comment: @Michael sure I can remember, [`LogManager.addPropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#addPropertyChangeListener-java.beans.PropertyChangeListener-) and `removePropertyChangeListener`, [removed in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#method.summary). I can remember because a) your right, “it almost never happens” and b) it happened fast, deprecated in JDK 8, removed in JDK 9. Still, I think, changing the semantics of `new` would be more disruptive than removing a few constructors.